# Como acceder a un diccionario desde una variable tipo string?

Tags: python, sql, variables

Tengo la siguiente inquietud.  Y es como puedo acceder a una variable que contiene un diccionario, desde otra variable que será un string, estoy haiciendo lo siguiente:

tengo una variable fecha que almacena los datos de año, mes y dia:

```
fecha = {'year': 2021, 'month': 5, 'day': 25}
```

y tengo otra variable que es tipo string al cual quiero acceder al diccionario, algo similiar a lo siguiente:

```
query = '''
SELECT estado, Plan, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin
FROM tabla_1
WHERE year = fecha['year'] and month = fecha['month'] and day = fecha['day']
'''
```

pero al momento de imprimir la variable query me queda igual a como esta copiada, es decir, no pone year = 2021 and month = 5 and day = 25

Comment: si lo pruebas a parte `print(fecha['year'])` eso dara `2021`,  no se si esas comillas podrian representar variables, recomiendo el uso de *f-strings*

Comment: hola Christian, me queda claro tu sugerencia ya probé y así me funciona perfecto.

Comment: Me alegro :), si tienes otro problema no dudes en hacer tu pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra alternativa es usar los f-string (*formatted strings*, *cadenas formateadas*), disponibles desde Python 3.6

Un f-string es un string al que se le antepone una letra `f`:

```
f"Nota: {nota}"
```

La gracia es que cualquier cosa que vaya entre corchetes es evaluado como una expresión Python y reemplazado dentro del string. Para imprimir un corchete, escribelo dos veces:

```
print(f"{{2 + 6}} = {2 + 6}") => {2 + 6} = 8
```

La mayor ventaja es que todo queda en un sólo lugar.

Con eso, el problema se resuelve así:

```
fecha = {'year': 2021, 'month': 5, 'day': 25}
query = f'''
SELECT estado, Plan, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin
FROM tabla_1
WHERE year = {fecha['year']} and month = {fecha['month']} and day = {fecha['day']}
'''

print(query)
```

produce

```
SELECT estado, Plan, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin
FROM tabla_1
WHERE year = 2021 and month = 5 and day = 25
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Me queda muy claro

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, la que más suelo usar es la función [format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format).

Por ejemplo

```
fecha = {'year': 2021, 'month': 5, 'day': 25}

query = '''
    SELECT estado, Plan, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin
    FROM tabla_1
    WHERE year = {year} and month = {month} and day = {day}
'''.format(**fecha)
```

De esta manera cada valor del diccionario pasara a la llave asignada

> Si la clave no existe en el diccionario, se lanza la excepción `KeyError`

También puedes usar la función `format` por posiciones

```
'''...
    WHERE year = {} and month = {} and day = {}
'''.format(fecha['year'], fecha['month'], fecha['day'])
```

Otra de las maneras es usar [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Por ejemplo

```
query = f'''
    SELECT estado, Plan, Fecha_Inicio, Fecha_Fin
    FROM tabla_1
    WHERE year = {fecha['year']} and month = {fecha['month']} and day = {fecha['day']}
'''
```

> PD: La pregunta ya esta resuelta(zona comentarios) pero dejo esto por aquí para futuros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema.

Comment: Gracias por contribuir, no crei necesario publicar una respuesta pero bien echo.